# C++, Searching strings in file using own criteria

Tags: c++, string

I am a beginner in C++, I want to create criteria to search the data into the file.
I need to find every sentence which contains `(3letters) (3-2letters) (value with at least 3 digits)`

Example of that sentence would be `ANT TRY 324`

Right now I am using `sentence = find(my_cell, "string")`

Comment: You should use a regular expression. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) is a tutorial on using them in C++

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you have tried so far and also a description of *exactly what you are having trouble with in that code.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl, i dont have any example i dont know how to start it. in place of "string" i need use something to get this sentence. i know that i can use `[[:digit:]]` but i dont know hot to connect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression would be

```
[A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{2,3} [0-9]{3,}
```

You can read about repetitions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and test it online [here](https://regex101.com/).

In C++ you can implement it like this:

```
#include <regex>
...
string str = "ANT TRY 324,ANT TR 32444";
const regex exp("[A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{2,3} [0-9]{3,}");
smatch res;
while (regex_search(str, res, exp)) {
    cout << res[0] << endl;
    str = res.suffix();
}
```